# How to replace all values in an object with strings using JS?

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I'm trying to get an array of JSON objects. To do that, I'm trying to make the input I have parsable, then parse it and push it to that array using a for loop.  The inputs I have to work with look like this:

```
firstname: Chris, lastname: Cheshire, email: chris@cmdcheshire.com, viewerlink: audiencematic.com/viewer?v\u003dTESTSHOW\u0026push\u003d8A043B5A, tempid: 8A043B5A, permaid: F8tGYNx, showid: TESTSHOW
```

I've gotten it to the point where each loop produces something like this:

```
{ "firstname": First Name, "lastname": Last Name, "email": sample@gmail.com, "viewerlink": audiencematic.com/viewer?v=TESTSHOW&push=715B3074, "tempid": 715B3074, "permaid": F8tGYNx, "showid": TESTSHOW }
```

But got stuck on the last bit, making the values strings. I want it to look like this, so I can use `JSON.parse()`:

```
{ "firstname": "First Name", "lastname": "Last Name", "email": "sample@gmail.com", "viewerlink": "audiencematic.com/viewer?v=TESTSHOW&push=715B3074", "tempid": "715B3074", "permaid": "F8tGYNx", "showed": "TESTSHOW" }
```

I tried a couple of different methods I found on here, but one of the values is a URL and the period is screwing with the replace expressions. I tried using the replace function like this:

```
var jsonStr2 = jsonStr.replace(/(: +\w)|(:+\w)/g, function(matchedStr) {
            return ':"' + matchedStr.substring(2, matchedStr.length) + '"';
        });
```

But it just becomes this:

```
{ "firstname":""irst Name, "lastname":""ast Name, "email":""ample@gmail.com, "viewerlink":""udiencematic.com/viewer?v=TESTSHOW&push=715B3074, "tempid":""15B3074, "permaid":""8tGYNx, "showid":""ESTSHOW }
```

How should I change my replace function?

(I tried that code because I'm using

```
var jsonStr = string.replace(/(\w+:)|(\w+ :)/g, function(matchedStr) {
            return '"' + matchedStr.substring(0, matchedStr.length - 1) + '":';
        });
```

to put parenthesis around the key sides and that seems to work.)

FIGURED IT OUT!! SEE MY ANSWER BELOW.

Comment: is your fake JSON composed of a single pair of brackets and does not contain any sub-objects ?

Comment: You say *"I have a JSON ..."*. Your input data is not [JSON](https://json.org). JSON is only the string you want to produce.

Comment: Sorry, I was using a single object as an example, I screwed up the terminology.I guess I'm asking how to replace all values in an object with strings. I'm doing this in a for loop and the input for this specific code is a single line.Editing the question

Comment: When editing your question, keep these things in mind: "JSON" stands for JavaScript Object Notation. It is a String, so you don't "have a JSON", you "have a JSON string". A JSON string gets turned into a Javascript Object by using `JSON.parse(theString)`  You can turn a Javascript Object into a JSON string by using `JSON.stringify(object) — so are you starting with a String, or are you starting with an Object?

Comment: How do you produce the string that starts with `{ "firstname": First Name, "lastname": ...` from the string that starts with `firstname: Chris, lastname: ...`? That code should not produce another string but an object you can then pass to `JSON.encode()` to get the expected result.

Comment: The code I'm using for that is ```var string = '{ ' + audiencelistdirty.feed.entry[i].content.$t +' }';```
     ```var jsonStr = string.replace(/(\w+:)|(\w+ :)/g, function(matchedStr) {
     return '"' + matchedStr.substring(0, matchedStr.length - 1) + '":';
  });```

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to try using a deserialized version of the string, alter the values associated with the properties of the object, and then convert back to a string.

```
var person = "{fname:\"John\", lname:\"Doe\", age:25}";
var obj = JSON.parse(person);  
for (x in obj) {
  obj[x] = "";
} 
var result = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

It's a little longer than doing a string replacement, but I find it a little easier to follow.

Comment: `JSON.parse(...)` won't work on the String that the OP has posted. Because the _values_ are not quoted it is invalid JSON and will throw an error. `let thestr = '{ "firstname": FirstName, "lastname": LastName }';` then `JSON.parse(thestr)` produces a Syntax Error.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Sorry, I completely misread the question. To replace the values with quoted strings use this regex replace function:

```
const str =
  'firstname: Chris, lastname: Cheshire, email: chris@cmdcheshire.com, viewerlink: audiencematic.com/viewer?v\u003dTESTSHOW\u0026push\u003d8A043B5A, tempid: 8A043B5A, permaid: F8tGYNx, showid: TESTSHOW'

const json = (() => {
  const result = str
    .replace(/\w+:\s(.*?)(?:,|$)/g, function (match, subStr) {
      return match.replace(subStr, `"${subStr}"`)
    })
    .replace(/(\w+):/g, function (match, subStr) {
      return match.replace(subStr, `"${subStr}"`)
    })
  return '{' + result + '}'
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I just had to mess around in regexr to figure out what conditions I needed. Here's the working for loop code:

```
for (i = 0; i < audiencelistdirty.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t; i++) {
        var string = '{ ' + audiencelistdirty.feed.entry[i].content.$t + ' }';
        var jsonStr = string.replace(/(\w+:)|(\w+ :)/g, function(matchedStr) {
                                return '"' + matchedStr.substring(0, matchedStr.length - 1) + '":';
                            });
        var jsonStr1 = jsonStr.replace(/(:(.*?),)|(:\s(.*?)\s)/g, function(matchedStr) {
            return ':"' + matchedStr.substring(2, matchedStr.length - 1) + '",';
        });
        var jsonStr2 = jsonStr1.replace(/(",})/g, function(matchedStr) {
            return '" }';
        });

        var newObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr2);
        audiencelist.push(newObj);
    };
```

It's pretty ugly but it works.

Comment: Where does this `audiencelistdirty.feed.entry...$t` come from? If _**that**_ is a javascript object you should be able to `JSON.stringify(...)` it and you wouldn't have to build it yourself — and it would quote everything properly.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the input string into commas then use a `regex` to identify the keys (between `,` and `:`) and their associated values (between `:` and `,`) and construct the object directly as in the example below:

```js
const input = ' firstname : Chris , lastname: Cheshire, email: chris@cmdcheshire.com, viewerlink: audiencematic.com/viewer?v\u003dTESTSHOW\u0026push\u003d8A043B5A, tempid: 8A043B5A, permaid: F8tGYNx, showid: TESTSHOW ';
const wrapped = `,${input},`;

const re = /,\s*([^:\s]*)\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*(?=,)/g;

const obj = {}
Array.from(wrapped.matchAll(re)).forEach((match) => obj[match[1]] = match[2]);
console.log(obj)
```

String.matchAll() is a newer function, not all JavaScript engines have implemented it yet. If you are one of the unlucky ones (or if you write code to be executed in a browser) then you can use the old-school way:

```js
const input = ' firstname : Chris , lastname: Cheshire, email: chris@cmdcheshire.com, viewerlink: audiencematic.com/viewer?v\u003dTESTSHOW\u0026push\u003d8A043B5A, tempid: 8A043B5A, permaid: F8tGYNx, showid: TESTSHOW ';
const wrapped = `,${input},`;

const re = /,\s*([^:\s]*)\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*(?=,)/g;

const obj = {}
let match = re.exec(wrapped);
while (match) {
  obj[match[1]] = match[2];
  match = re.exec(wrapped);
}
console.log(obj);
```

### The anatomy of the `regex` used above

The regular expression piece by piece:

```
/          # regex delimiter; not part of the regex but JavaScript syntax
 ,         # match a comma
 \s        # match a white space character (space, tab, new line)
 *         # the previous symbol zero or more times
 (         # start the first capturing group; does not match anything
  [        # start a character class...
   ^       # ... that matches any character not listed inside the class
    :      # ... i.e. any character but semicolon...
    \s     # ... and white space character
  ]        # end of the character class; the entire class matches only one character
  *        # the previous symbol zero or more times
 )         # end of the first capturing group; does not match anything
 \s*:\s*   # zero or more spaces before and after the semicolon
 (         # start of the second capturing group
  .*       # any character, any number of times; this is greedy by default
  ?        # make it not greedy
 )         # end of the second capturing group
 \s*       # zero or more spaces
 (?=       # lookahead positive assertion; matches but does not consume  the matched substring
  ,        # matches a comma
 )         # end of the assertion
 /         # regex delimiter; not part of the regex but JavaScript 
 g         # regex flag; 'g' for 'global' is needed to find all matches
```

Read about the [syntax of regular expressions in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). For a more comprehensive description of the `regex` patterns I recommend reading the PHP documentation of [PCRE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) (Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions).

You can see the regex in action and play with it on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/zhbMZp/1).